# Why doesn't my MacOS or Windows OS detect a Kali linux installed hard disk as an external drive?

Tags: windows-10, macos, kali-linux

I have installed Kali Linux on a hard disk. I removed it and connected via USB to my MacOS (also tried WindowsOS). I want to take backup of files in Kali Linux. But the hard disk is not detected. How to solve this?

After comments, `diskutil list` results

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell what you're actually trying to achieve… Are you trying to boot from it, or just make a copy of the USB from your currently-running OS?

Comment: @Tetsujin Trying to copy files from the hard disk that has Kali Linux via USB. Definitely not trying to boot from it.

Comment: What's the format? Mac can read most things natively, even if it can't write… but if it's ExtFS you're going to need 3rd party software.

Comment: @Tetsujin how can I find the format of my external hard which has Kali?

Comment: try `diskutil list` from Terminal

Comment: @Tetsujin APFS /dev/disk1 (synthesized):

Comment: Well, that's not the USB, that's your boot drive… if disk1 is synthesized, then you only have one physical device, disk0. Best guess right now is your kali drive is… broken, but I really can't tell from so little info.

Comment: @Tetsujin hmm. Here are more details. https://imgur.com/a/xsjTEXr

Comment: I inlined your picture. Your labelling is incorrect, `disk1(synthesized)` is a virtual drive, that your Mac is currently booted from. `disk0` is the physical source of that, which I can see from the FFFFF partition that you've already messed with it & managed to break, quite badly. Your USB is nowhere to be seen. I'm back to "it's broken". Your physical  boot drive is also broken [mis-formatted], but for different, unrelated reasons.

Comment: Well, I was sure I inlined your picture… done again...

Comment: @Tetsujin But the hard disk that has kali works fine if it is  put back into original laptop

Comment: @sofs1 sounds like the enclosure is bad.

Comment: @At0mic - Any recommendations for good enclosures?